# Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

On this code:

```
SELECT 
dest.text 
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
AS 
deqs 
CROSS 
APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_sql_text
(
deqs.sql_handle    -- This is line 11.
) 
AS 
dest 
WHERE 
deqs.last_execution_time 
> 
'2018-07-01 00:00:00' 
AND 
dest.text 
LIKE 
'%QuittanceAudit%'
;
```

I spread that code out on multiple lines so that the error message could more precisely report the location of the error.

Or, in a standard format:

```
SELECT dest.text 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs 
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest 
 WHERE deqs.last_execution_time > '2018-07-01 00:00:00' 
   AND dest.text LIKE '%QuittanceAudit%'
;
```

The problem I am trying to solve is getting the history of the select statements that have run using this technique:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/can-i-see-historical-queries-run-on-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there is nothing wrong in your syntax, it runs fine on my server.

Are you using a user account different from `sa`?

To run `dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle)` you need `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission on the server and to run `dm_exec_query_stats` you need both `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission on the server and `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission in the database.

Try this:

```
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO YourUserAccount
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO YourUserAccount
```